# VB 2008 Log in Username and password withg MS ACCESS

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

i just need a little help here, I already have a log in, but i just want to create a prompt that if I input a incorrect username and correct password, the dialog box says that the username only is incorrect and if vise versa, dialog box says that the password is incorrect. and if both username and password is incorrect, dialog box says username and password is incorrect. It is connected in MS ACCESS, here is my code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim connection As New OleDbConnection

    connection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    connection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;; Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\Data.mdb"

    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT User,Password FROM tblUser where User=? and Password=?", connection)

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("User", Me.TextBox1.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Password", Me.TextBox2.Text)

    Try
        connection.Open()
        Dim read As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        If read.HasRows Then
            read.Read()

            If Me.TextBox1.Text.ToLower() = read.Item("user").ToString And Me.TextBox2.Text.ToLower = read.Item("Password").ToString Then
                MsgBox("Login successful")
                Me.Hide()
                Form2.Show()

            End If

        Else
            MsgBox("Login unsuccessful,no connection", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Invalid")
        End If

        read.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        connection.Close()
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Although I understand the question, it's much more secure not to give the user any clue about which part of their credentials is wrong.

Comment: @RogerRowland There is no error or wrong in my codes. im just showing it for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim connection As New OleDbConnection

    connection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    connection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;; Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\Data.mdb"

    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT User,Password FROM tblUser where User=?", connection)

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("User", Me.TextBox1.Text)

    Try
        connection.Open()
        Dim read As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        If read.HasRows Then
            read.Read()

            If Me.TextBox2.Text.ToLower = read.Item("Password").ToString Then
                MsgBox("Login successful")
                Me.Hide()
                Form2.Show()
            Else
                MsgBox("Login unsuccessful, Incorrect Password", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Invalid")
            End If

        Else
            MsgBox("Login unsuccessful, Invalid UserName", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Invalid")
        End If
        read.Close()
    Catch ex As OleDbException
        MsgBox("Login unsuccessful,no connection", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Invalid")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        connection.Close()
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for this! it helps a lot, but theres only a little problem now, I want to display that if the user and password is wrong, i want to display it that "INVALID USERNAME AND PASSWORD" in your program, it will only say that "INVALID USER" even the password is wrong also. thanks in advance!

Comment: @EysAce, When the UserName is wrong, there is no way to locate the record in the database. So you don't know whether the password is correct or not, until you know the username you are looking at. Well ofcourse you could query on the password field, but that becomes risky, because two users can keep the same password. So anyone with malicious intents can come to know that a particular password exists in the database, thus exposing your application to security threats. If you know what I mean!